# Is it possible to do rolling operations on Dask DataFrames where the entire DataFrame slice is passed to apply?

Tags: dask

I am trying to do a rolling operation on a Dask DataFrame, and need to apply a function on two columns of the DataFrame (calculate a cross-correlation). DataFrame rolling appears to operate on columns separately and sequentially. Is there a way to roll through a DataFrame and give the applied function access to more than one column of the DataFrame?